# PHP switching tabs in browsers causes session not work and must relogin

Tags: php, browser, authentication, session, tabs

I have a password protected area of a site that I use Sessions to allow the user to move from page to page of the protected area. However if I open new tab YET keep the other tab open (the one in the protected area) and then do somethings in the new tab and switch back then to the old tab I am forced to re login. I have tried setting the expiration date to twenty minutes between sessions but I am having no luck. Any ideas?

```
// set expiration time of 20 mins
session_cache_expire (20);
$cache_expire = session_cache_expire();
```

Comment: Is the new tab of the protected area? Sounds more like a browser bug the way you describe it... A tab will never interfere with the sessions/cookies of another unless it's the same website. What script is being run in the secure area? Perhaps it's unsetting the session due to inactivity.

Comment: Please show some more code. How are you initializing the session?

Comment: How does your system check/maintain the state of “being logged in”?

Comment: session_cache_expire has nothing to do with lifetime or expiration time. See: The first comment in the manual: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-cache-expire.php#81265

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is the protected area a subdirectory of the url you're loading in the other tab? This can cause cookies to get screwed up, because the first cookie can be set for a more specific path than the url of the second page, so a new session is started.

This guy does a better job of explaining it:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php#91298

> If two different files don't access
>   the same session, it can only mean one
>   thing: they aren't on the same
>   directory level.  Examples:  a) One is
>   under https, and one is under http.
>   (very common and annoying error)  b)
>   One is under /, another is under
>   /dir1, and /dir1 was first to run. The
>   cookie created by the session is for
>   /dir1 and deeper only, so the other
>   script can't read it; it sees no
>   session so it starts a new one.
>
> Solutions:
>
> 1) Session start should
>   always happen at root dir. If one of
>   your scripts discovers user is not
>   logged in, for example, use
>   session_destroy() and send him to the
>   login in the root dir. Scripts that
>   use session without requiring login
>   needs more creative solutions, like
>   redirecting to the root dir, setting
>   the session, and redirecting back.
>
> 2)
>   Use SID from page to page, instead of
>   cookies. The upside is that this also
>   works with http/https. The downside is
>   very ugly URL codes and more difficult
>   maintainability ('which pages links to
>   gallery.php without using SID?!').

Comment: The session is set in a subfolder. I will try and redirect to the root and then back to see if that fixes it?

Comment: So if a user loads example.com/subdir first, a call to session_start() will set the session for ONLY that subdir?  That seems like a bad default.  Is there a way to turn that off?